# What’s the difference between rootkit and RAT?

Tags: windows, malware, malware-removal, trojan

I know that both can give attacker remote access to computer. Is RAT easier to detect than rootkit? Where are they typically get installed? Can one make more damage than another? Which one is easier to remove?

Answer (score 1):

From [Kaspersky - A Malware Classification](https://www.kaspersky.co.uk/blog/a-malware-classification/2620/)

> Rootkit:
> A rootkit is a special form of malware, designed specifically to hide its presence and actions from both the user and any existing protection software they have installed on their system. It’s able to do this via deep integration with the operating system, sometimes even starting before the operating system does (this variety of rootkit has its own name, bootkits). Sophisticated antivirus software is still able to detect rootkits and get rid of them though.
>
> Backdoor (RAT):
> A Backdoor, or a Remote Administration Tool, is an application that allows a person (the system administrator or a cybercriminal) access to a computer system without user consent or knowledge. Depending on the RAT functionality, an attacker could install and launch other software, send keystrokes, download or delete files, switch the microphone and/or camera on, or log computer activity and send it back to the attacker.

For the rest of your questions, see [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)